# Validation error with foreign key

Tags: entity-framework-5

When I have this simple model:

```
public class User
{
    // Primary key
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Int32 FailedPasswordAttemptCount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Language Language { get; set; }
} 
public class Language
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid LanguageId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public String LocaleName { get; set; }
}
```

And I do this code:

```
var user = context.Users.Single(u => u.UserId == userId);
user.FailedPasswordAttemptCount++;
context.SaveChanges();
```

It will throw an `DbEntityValidationException` expception `The Language field is required.`.

Technically this is true because the property is marked as required and because the `Language` property is null when fetched from the database (no lazy or eager loading).

But how do I change this behaviour?

- I don't want to disable validation completely
- I don't want to lazy / eager load the field
- I don't want to remove the Required tag from the model

What other options are out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent this by adding the primitive FK field (probably `LanguageId`) to your `User` class. This is not uncommon in entity framework. There are more occasions where getting or setting the primitive property saves work or unnecessary (lazy) loading.

Comment: Thanks I added a `Guid` `LanguageId` to the User class which I didn't make required and that worked fine.